# Append multiple pandas columns into a list

Tags: pandas, string, list, dataframe

I have a df that consists of multiple columns. I would like to take a subset of my df and append those columns into a list. They are all strings.

Sample df

```
A         B       C       D       E       F
word1   word2   word3   word4   word5   word6   
word7   word8   word9   word1   word2   word3 
word4   word5   word6   word7   word8   word9 
word1   word2   word3   word4   word5   word6 
word7   word8   word9   word1   word2   word3
```

So I would take, for example, column C, E, and F and append them together as a list.

Desired output

```
list = [word3, word9, word6, word3, word9, 
        word5, word2, word8, word5, word2, 
        word6, word3, word9, word6, word3]
```

Thanks in advance! Much appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

Use `pandas.melt` with `tolist`:

```
df[["C", "E", "F"]].melt()["value"].tolist()
```

Output:

```
['word3',
 'word9',
 'word6',
 'word3',
 'word9',
 'word5',
 'word2',
 'word8',
 'word5',
 'word2',
 'word6',
 'word3',
 'word9',
 'word6',
 'word3']
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution with [`numpy.ravel`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html):

```
L = np.ravel(df[['C','E','F']].to_numpy().T).tolist()
print (L)
['word3', 'word9', 'word6', 'word3', 'word9', 
 'word5', 'word2', 'word8', 'word5', 'word2', 
 'word6', 'word3', 'word9', 'word6', 'word3']
```

Or like @sammywemmy solution:

```
L = np.ravel(df[['C','E','F']].to_numpy(), order="F").tolist()
```